# Pygame problem using list from list to create instance

Tags: python, list, class, pygame

So i'm trying to shoot a bullet. the idea is to create a list with the variables needed to create and bullet instance and add that list to a list. then i create a bullet instance from the last item in the list that contains lists. sadly i  got the "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable" for the line where i try to create a new bullet instance. i hope you can help me, the variable names should be self explaining.

```
def shoot(self):
        if self.bullets_isshot == True:
            self.m_x, self.m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            self.bullets_new_bullet = (self.m_x, self.m_y, self.cords_x, self.cords_y)
            self.bullets_list.append(self.bullets_new_bullet)
            for bullet in self.bullets_list:
                if bullet == self.bullets_list[-1]:
                    new_bullet = bullet(bullet[0], bullet[1], bullet[2], bullet[3])
            self.bullets_isshot = False
```

and in case you need it the bullet **init** method:

```
def __init__(self, target_x, target_y, player_x, player_y):
        #var img, cords
        self.img = fast_load_img('/data/img/bullets/fireball.png')
        self.width = 128
        self.height = self.width
        self.x = player_x
        self.y = player_y
        self.target_x = target_x
        self.target_y = target_y
        self.d_x = self.target_x - self.x
        self.d_y = self.target_y - self.y

        #var vel, angle
        self.vel = 5
        self.angle = math.atan2(self.d_x, self.d_y)
        self.x_change = self.vel * math.cos(self.angle)
        self.y_change = self.vel * math.sin(self.angle)
```

Comment: Look at your data types.  You have a `list` of `tuple`, but you're trying to invoke/call the tuple which is an invalid action.  You're not actually instantiating the class

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley i just realized it to and changed the tuple to a list but is didnt make any difference except it says "list" object not callable now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're creating a list of a single item, then iterating over it.  This is unnecessary.

You don't really need the list or the tuple at all.  Just create a new bullet with the class constructor.  You don't seem to store the new bullet anywhere, so I've just returned it from the function.  Probably you should store it in a list or suchlike (assuming more than a single bullet is on-screen at a time).

```
def shoot( self ):
    """ If the player has fired a shot, create a new bullet.
        Returns the new bullet or None """
    new_bullet = None
    if self.bullets_isshot == True:
        self.m_x, self.m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        new_bullet = bullet( self.m_x, self.m_y, self.cords_x, self.cords_y )
        self.bullets_isshot = False 
    return new_bullet
```